# Environment variable is not realized correctly

Tags: powershell

When I use the `$Env:ProgramFiles(x86)` environment variable, there is no space character before the opening parenthesis. How can I get PowerShell to produce the necessary space? PSVersion 5.0.10586.117

```
PS C:\src\powershell\t> "$Env:ProgramFiles(x86)"
C:\Program Files(x86)
PS C:\src\powershell\t> Get-ChildItem "$Env:ProgramFiles(x86)"
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Program Files(x86)' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem "$Env:ProgramFiles(x86)"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Program Files(x86):String) [Get-ChildItem]
   , ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the space that's missing, it's that it isn't interpreting the parentheses as part of the variable name.

Use the `${name}` variable syntax.

Anything in the braces is treated as part of the variable name, including spaces, punctuation, special characters, even newlines.

```
${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}
```

If you were to tab complete `$env:Progr`<kbd>TAB</kbd> it would insert the braces for you.

Comment: Thanks. I see now.