# encapsulating strings with whitespaces in gitlab ci yaml

Tags: powershell, yaml, gitlab-ci

How do I specify a string literal which contains whitespaces in a GitLab CI YAML file?

For example, I am using to call msbuild.exe which is located at C:\Program Files (x86)...\msbuild.exe in gitlab-ci.yml file as follows

```
build:
   - C:\Program Files (x86)\...\msbuild.exe MySolution.sln
```

I tried using both single quotes and double quotes to encapsulate the path, but fails lint.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to that as well, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick:

```yaml
- . 'C:\Program Files (x86)\{...}'
```

Please note the PowerShell [Dot sourcing operator .](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/331) talks about the same problem. Its 3 years old and since then GitLab changed a lot of stuff and the answer in the link is no longer relevant. One of the things they changed is that when the runner set to be of `shell` type it is now uses `Windows PowerShell` instead of cmd.exe. There for, here is an example of a solution that works for me:

1. Have a `build.bat` file ready with something like this:

   ```
   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
   Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" some_solution.sln /m 
   /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64`.
   ```

   Commit it as part of your repo.
2. Have the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file look like this:

   ```
   build_job:
     script: .\build.bat
   ```

Answer (score 0):

What you would do normally is this (env is optional but improve [readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714877/setting-windows-powershell-environment-variables)):

```yaml
build:
  variables:
    DUMP_ENV: 'env:'
    vswhere: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe'
  stage: build
  script:
    - dir ${DUMP_ENV}
    - . $env:vswhere -products *
```

The following is invalid YAML, even though this would be [valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639894/executing-an-exe-file-using-a-powershell-script) [powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72439724/how-to-run-vswhere-on-powershell) syntax:

```
    - & $env:vswhere -products *
```

Consider:

```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -products *
At line:1 char:72
+ ... iles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -products *
+                                                               ~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token '-products' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:82
+ ... iles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -products *
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token '*' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

while:

```
> & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -products *
Visual Studio Locator version 2.7.1+180c706d56 [query version 2.11.65.22356]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

instanceId: 43cea1ed
installDate: 2/15/2021 10:35:51 AM
installationName: VisualStudio/16.11.19+32901.82
installationPath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise
...
```

If you had used the default shell for windows syntax [would have been](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/331):

```yaml
variables:
  nuget: 'c:\nuget\nuget.exe'
  msbuild: '"c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe"'

compile:
  stage: build
  script:
    - '%nuget% restore'
    - '%msbuild% ...'
```

---

Watch out that for [env variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#with-powershell) you cannot simply use:

```yaml
build:
  variables:
    vswhere: '"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"'
```

Simply because [`ProgramFiles(x86)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44142841/environment-variable-is-not-realized-correctly) will be evaluated [before](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/35066) the environement is loaded. So the env var would result in:

```
vswhere                       "\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
```

In which case you must define your env variable within your script steps:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - $env:vswhere="${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
    - . $env:vswhere -products *
```