# How to run vswhere on powershell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I found this script for finding where msbuild.exe is, but it's not working. When I run it, it says "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'latest'" https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-MSBuild

Here is my script:

```
$path = %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -find MSBuild\**\Bin\MSBuild.exe | select-object -first 1
if ($path) {
  & $path $args
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I tried encapsulating the path in quotes, and putting it into a variable and tried using `Invoke-Expression` but this also did not work. In bash all I would need to do is encapsulate the command with ` and it would work.

```
 Invoke-Expression -Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
x86: The term 'x86' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

This also does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here I am expliclty creating a list of arguments in seperate strings.

```
$path = "$(${env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)})\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" 
$args = "-latest", "-requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild", "-find MSBuild\**\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

if ($path) {
  Start-Process $path -ArgumentList $args
}
```

I am unable to test as i dont have Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This is "small" script which I wrote.

It will:

1. download latest recomended Nuget.exe in same directory where this PS script will be saved.
2. download/install "vswhere" nuget (in script directory)
3. will find latest  "MSBuild.exe"  path

`$latestRecomendedUrl = "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe"
$currentScriptDir = "$PSScriptRoot"
$nuget = Join-Path "$currentScriptDir" "nuget.exe"
if (!(Test-Path "$nuget" -pathType Leaf)) {
    # download if not exists
    Invoke-WebRequest "$latestRecomendedUrl" -OutFile "$nuget" | Out-Null
}

$vswhereExePartFromScriptDir = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$currentScriptDir" -Filter "vswhere.exe" -Recurse -Name)
$vswhereExe = Join-Path "$currentScriptDir" "$vswhereExePartFromScriptDir"

if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($vswhereExePartFromScriptDir)) {
    try {
        $args = "install", "-x", "-o", "$currentScriptDir", "vswhere"
        &"$nuget" $args
        Write-Host "Nuget was successfully downloaded."
    }
    finally {
        $vswhereExePartFromScriptDir = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$currentScriptDir" -Filter "vswhere.exe" -Recurse -Name)
        $vswhereExe = Join-Path "$currentScriptDir" "$vswhereExePartFromScriptDir"
        # in my case install throws error #"nuget.exe : The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."#
        # but it download vswhere package successfully - so throw error only if it does not exist
        if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($vswhereExePartFromScriptDir)) {
            Write-Error "Failed to download 'vswhere.exe'."
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "vswhere executable: ""$vswhereExe"""
        }
    }
}
else {
    Write-Host "vswhere executable: ""$vswhereExe"""
}
$args = "-latest", "-products", "*", "-requires", "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild", "-find", "MSBuild\**\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
$msbuildExe = $(& "$vswhereExe" $args) | select-object -first 1
Write-Host "MSBuild exeutable: ""$msbuildExe"""`

Output:

`Feeds used:
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
    Installing package 'vswhere' to 'G:\scripts\ps'.
      CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration5-gz-semver2/vswhere/index.json
    Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'vswhere.3.1.1' with respect to project 'G:\scripts\ps', targeting 'Any,    Version=
    v0.0'
    Gathering dependency information took 15 ms
    Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'vswhere.3.1.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
    Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
    Resolving actions to install package 'vswhere.3.1.1'
    Resolved actions to install package 'vswhere.3.1.1'
    Retrieving package 'vswhere 3.1.1' from 'nuget.org'.
    Adding package 'vswhere.3.1.1' to folder 'G:\scripts\ps'
    WARNING: Install failed. Rolling back...
    Executing nuget actions took 483 ms
    nuget.exe : The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.
    At G:\scripts\ps\Get-MsBuildDir.ps1:21 char:9
    +         &"$nuget" $args
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The requested o...d section open.:String) [], RemoteException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    Nuget was successfully downloaded.
    vswhere executable: "G:\scripts\ps\vswhere\tools\vswhere.exe"
    MSBuild exeutable: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"`