# Unexpected token '-property' in expression or statement

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-installer

Hi everyone I am trying to fetch the version of Microsoft Visual Studio components from powershell
I tried
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -property catalog_productDisplayVersion
command But its working only on 'command Prompt'

I ran this command,
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -property catalog_productDisplayVersion

output:
At line:1 char:72

- ... x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -property catalog ...
- ```
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~
  ```

Unexpected token '-property' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:82

- ... Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -property catalog_productDisplayVersion
- ```
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

Unexpected token 'catalog_productDisplayVersion' in expression or statement.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: I have removed some of your tags, as this question is specifically about an error resulting only when running in PowerShell. Also, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72439724) help/

Comment: In short: An executable path that is _quoted_ or contains _variable references_ must - for syntactic reasons - be invoked with `&`, the [call operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-); see the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefix the command with the [PowerShell "Call Operator"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1#call-operator-), which is an ampersand:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -property catalog_productDisplayVersion
```

It prevents PowerShell from trying to parse the string.

Comment: Good point re `&`, but let me clarify, since "trying to parse the string" is a bit ambiguous: It's about whether a statement is parsed as a _command_ (argument mode)  or an _expression_ (expression mode), as discussed in the [about_Parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Parsing) help topic. A _quoted_ token at the start of a statement is interpreted as a _string literal_ starting an _expression_. Starting a statement with `&` forces interpretation as a _command_, ensuring that the quoted string is interpreted as a command/executable.

Comment: How to use call(&) operator in batch script,

Comment: @ashish, `cmd.exe`'s batch language uses `&` exclusively  for _separating statements_ (PowerShell uses `;`). Unlike PowerShell, it requires _no_ operator in order to invoke executables whose names / paths are quoted; e.g., `"where.exe" findstr` works just fine.